# robot_localization debug file

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using robot_localization to doing EKF.
And I want to output the debug file, but when I set the parameter in .yaml like this

```
debug: true
debug_out_file: ~/debug/file.txt
```

and run the lauch.
But I don't see any file in ~/debug

Why is that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289091/robot_localization-debug-file/) by [Jacky](https://answers.ros.org/users/34237/jacky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried using an absolute path? I don’t think the method of file opening that i’m using resolves the ~.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jacky](https://answers.ros.org/users/34237/jacky/) on 2018-04-19**:
ok, it shows up. Thanks!